# apply multiple filter conditions and produce only one element from a list

Tags: scala

say for e.g.

```
scala> case class Entitlement(read: Boolean, edit: Boolean, create: Boolean, delete: Boolean)
defined class Entitlement

scala> List (Entitlement(read= true, edit = true, create= false, delete =false),Entitlement(read= true, edit = false, create= false, delete =false),Entitlement(read= true, edit = true, create= false, delete =true))
res0: List[Entitlement] = List(Entitlement(true,true,false,false), 
Entitlement(true,false,false,false), Entitlement(true,true,false,true))
```

Is there a way to create ONE and ONLY one `Entitlement(true,true,false,true)` with a single pass of a List `res0` such that it'll go thru the list and if `read=true` found that's the final `read` privilege `else default value for read=false` - if `edit=true` found that's the final `edit` privilege `else default value for edit=false` and so on. in this toy example `create=false` in all of the `Entitlement` elements in the `List` why final result will be

```
Entitlement(true,true,false,true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fold your list and `or` together the corresponding values of the `Entitlement`s. You start with an `Entitlement` with all values set to false.

```
res0.fold(Entitlement(false, false, false, false))((e1, e2) => 
    Entitlement(
        e1.read || e2.read, 
        e1.edit || e2.edit, 
        e1.create || e.create,
        e1.delete || e2.delete))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with reduce too. Below is an example. The advantage here is that you do not need to pass an initial value and it is more intuitive.

```
res0.reduce((e1, e2) => Entitlement(e1.read | e2.read, e1.edit | e2.edit, e1.create | e2.create, e1.delete | e2.delete))
```

Comment: The disadvantage is that it won't work if `res0` can be empty.

Comment: Yes. Agree. If the list can be empty, then fold is the right option.